# Is it true about Arrows?

Tags: haskell, arrows

Somewhere I read that Arrows allow to avoid/simplify monads' transformations (as for me, monad transformers look the most inelegant idiom in Haskell). Is it true? Can somebody show me some small example how Arrows solve transformation when I need to have "stack" with 2 effects?

Comment: This may in some cases be possible, but IMO it's missing the point to just see arrows as an “alternative to monads”. They're not really practical to think about, in that role; fixation on this point is one of the reasons why arrows are so underrepresented in the Haskell ecosystem. I generally consider arrows as just _functions with optional extra bells_ (general morphisms, actually). — The “proper idiom for monad transformers“ would actually be _functor composition_, which doesn't have very much to do with arrows (except insofar as all this category-theory is tightly connected).

Comment: hm. OK. As for me, most attractive about arrows is possibilities to get alternative to transformers (I don't like them;) and second is that seems they can replace streaming/piping libraries. But I never try them and don't know will they simplify or complicate all. When I see arrow-based libs documentation, all looks very simple, cool and beauty.

Comment: There are (seldom used) arrow transformers as well: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arrows-0.4.4.1/docs/Control-Arrow-Transformer.html

Comment: @Paul-AG I guess one question is, why don't you like monad transformers? Monad transformers were made to make things easier. There are some alternatives. The "straightforward" way to implement something without them would involve a lot of boilerplate (since it would be just a bunch of nested types, with no "helpers" to deal with the nesting). Also, no, I don't think arrows have any relation to avoiding/replacing monad transformers.

Comment: sounds strange, bcz example in "Haskell Design Patterns" shows how simple is to switch from Monads to Arrows and get equivalent functionality. But more interesting: isn't simple to turn monad-code to streaming w/o special libs (conduit/pipes/etc), but seems it's simple w/ Arrows. May be Arrows can eliminate streaming-libs even? Transformers are easy to understand and terrible to read as code. Even more: ListT bug shows that even good Haskellers does not understand what are they doing w/ transformers :) So I supposed, Arrows can help to avoid some design problems in Haskell (transformers).

Comment: I found [this](http://karols.github.io/blog/2014/04/29/from-nested-monads-to-kleisli-arrows-over-monad-transformers/), so I'' keep it here, maybe someone will be interested